# reading file into a char array and then calculating strlen gets stuck in C++

Tags: c++

I have the following C program

```
f = fopen("input", "r");
char line[1024];
while ((fgets(line, 1024, f)) != NULL) {
    cout << strlen(line) << endl;
    exit(1);//just to see what went wrong.
}
fclose(f);
```

It looks like it will get stuck when evaluating `strlen(line)`. But it seems strange to me, since I checked individual characters of line, and I found `line[3]=='\0'`. So why would it be non-stopping?

Comment: This isn't C code so please don't use `fopen`, use `fstream`. Updated tags

Comment: Alternatively, make it C code by not using cout and using `printf` instead. :)

Comment: Why on earth would he want to do that?

Comment: right, guys, the question in essence is C in nature.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: what do you mean?

Comment: @littleEinstein why is it "C in nature" if you're using C++?

Comment: it is because the evaluation of strlen

Comment: no ... it's because of cout ... use printf instead. printf("%s", line) will extract the null terminated string from an otherwise full of data char

Comment: But the point is why would he want to do that? That's a step backwards when he's already using C++; there's no reason to limit himself to C

Comment: printf("%d",strlen(line)); got me non-stopping too.

Comment: While the two languages may share some syntax, functions and libraries, '**C**' and '**C++**' are different languages. You need to be clear (in your own mind and in your question) which of these you are using.

Comment: @Johnsyweb: Actually this question is about why this specific code does not work, which is completely unrelated to the question how this code should look like if it was written more idiomatically.

Comment: I feel you guys are not discussing the essence of the problem, while focusing on the different terms I used in the question. At the least, my code is valid, and the problem is clear. I should have used printf and stated myself better.

Comment: @NiklasBaumstark: I cannot agree you more!!

Comment: As you see, I am reading only the first line and exit. And I tested line[3]=='\0'. The first line has only 3 chars including `\n`.

Comment: @littleEinstein: It wasn't clear that your program fails on that particular line of input. I can't reproduce this behaviour with a line containing only two characters plus newline.

Comment: please note, this is unix file rather than windows file. But I guess it does not matter, as I converted to Windows file, I still got stuck, the programs runs forever. why? why!

Comment: Can you debug your code?

Comment: Maybe the problem is not `strlen` but the printing to `stdout` – maybe `stdout` was closed before (would this be undifined behaviour?)

Comment: @ChristianAmmer: I tried to debug, the program runs forever at `cout << strlen(line) << endl;` or `printf("%d",strlen(line));` if it matters.

Comment: @littleEinstein: Can you split the statements to see if it is the printing or the strlen? Can you print anything else – I once had a problem with a closed `stdout`, a leftover `printf` command corrupted a datafile!

Comment: good point. If I do `int l=strlen(line);`, it stuck.

Comment: Then I only can think of a non standard `strlen` function (overwitten by another) or you have another thread which overwrites `line`. Both is very unlikely but what else could be the reason?

Comment: @littleEinstein: Can you make a self-contained example with the failing input file along with it? I don't think you'll get a good answer otherwise, your code as such seems to be okay.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to reproduce your problem.

Here is my input... two lines of two printable ASCII characters, one of 1,025 and one with unprintable characters. All with DOS line-endings on a Mac.:

```
> cat -vet input 
ab^M$
qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq^M$
12^M$
^A^B^C^M$
```

Here is a modified version of your program:

```
> cat mongrel.cpp 
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    FILE* f = fopen("input", "r");
    char line[1024];
    while ((fgets(line, 1024, f)) != NULL) {
        const size_t len = strlen(line);
        for (char* cp = line; cp < line + len; ++cp)
        {
            cout << std::hex << static_cast<int>(*cp) << ' ';
        }

        cout << '\n' << strlen(line) << endl;
    }
    fclose(f);
}
```

Built using G++:

```
> make mongrel
g++     mongrel.cpp   -o mongrel
```

And run:

```
> ./mongrel      
61 62 d a 
4
71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 
3ff
71 71 d a 
4
31 32 d a 
4
1 2 3 d a 
5
```

It behaves as expected and reads just the 1,023 characters (leaving space for `\000`) on the first attempt at reading the long line, and has newlines at the end of each line, as you'd expect. You can see I have even tried with unprintable characters (`0x01`, `0x02`, `0x03`, ...) and DOS-style newlines (`0x0D0A`) and it continues to behave.

Your problem must be elsewhere. Your debugger will tell you for sure.

---

Out of curiosity, what does the following program output?

```
> cat pedigree.cpp 
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream f("input");
    if (f)
    {
        std::transform(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(f),
            std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
            std::ostream_iterator<size_t>(std::cout, "\n"),
            [](std::string line) { return line.length(); }
            );
    }
}
```

Build with:

```
> make pedigree
g++ -std=c++0x pedigree.cpp   -o pedigree
```

I see:

```
> ./pedigree 
2
1025
2
3
```

Comment: my file is like `20$
2$
2$...
` does not seems to be a big difference. I can cout/printf the first line after reading it. But when printf/cout the strlen, it got stuck.

Comment: it is the place `int l=strlen(line);` that is causing the problem.

Comment: What happened when you stepped through `strlen()` in the debugger?

Comment: *Your own version of `strlen()`*? I did say the problem must be elsewhere!

Comment: thanks for the debugging tip. i did not think going deeper into the function initially. :)

Comment: @littleEinstein: Happy to help. But why, *why*, **why** did you write your own `strlen()`?

Answer (score 1):

You have code that definitely should work. The problem is not in the code you pasted. Possible problem sources are:

1) Do you have the appropriate '#include' directives?

2) Is your compiler, library, environment, or system broken?

3) Are you running this code combined with other code that corrupts the environment somehow?

4) Are you in an unusual environment where this is not supposed to work? (For example, a microcontroller with a very limited stack.)

Comment: 1)yes. 2)no, at least not i know of. Should be all right. 3) shouldn't be. I placed my code in a named namespace. Should not interfere elsewhere and only used `using namespace std;`. 4) just normal PC environment.

Comment: Mystery solved! @littleEinstein wrote a custom, buggy `strlen()`.